# If column A=X then copy value of column B

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with the following headings

[Name] [Surname]

I want to create a list that is basically "Name | Surname, Surname, Surname".

In my first sheet I will then have data that will for example be

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| Jane | Smith |
| Jane | Doe |
| Jane | Brown |

And I'm trying to pull through the surnames into one list, if they share the same first name. I've tried `=VLOOKUP("Jane",{'Names'!A:A, 'Names'!B:B}, 2, 0)` but this is only pulling through the first result and I'm unsure if I can create a list in one cell or if this is not possible at all.

Any help would be appreciated please.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _manually entered_ desired results there.

Answer (score 1):

Use `filter()`, like this:

`=filter(Names!B2:B, Names!A2:A = "Jane")`

To put all matching names in one cell with separators between, use `join()`, like this:

`=join( ", ", filter(Names!B2:B, Names!A2:A = "Jane") )`

Answer (score 0):

If you want them to remain separated in columns, you can do a pivot with this

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  QUERY(
   QUERY(
    {A2:B,COUNTIFS(A2:A,A2:A,ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A))},
    "select Col1, Max(Col2)
     where Col1 is not null
     group by Col1
     pivot Col3"),
   "offset 1",0))
```

If you want them comma separated with the pipe like this

```
Name1 | Last1, Last2, Last3, Last4, Last5
Name2 | Last1, Last2
```

you can use this

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  REGEXREPLACE(
   TRIM(
    TRANSPOSE(
      QUERY(
       TRANSPOSE(
        QUERY(
         QUERY(
          {A2:A&" |",B2:B&",",COUNTIFS(A2:A,A2:A,ROW(A2:A),"<="&ROW(A2:A))},
          "select Col1, Max(Col2)
           where Col3 >=1
           group by Col1
           pivot Col3"),
         "offset 1",0)),,
       1E+100))),
    ",$",""))
```